# Connect EC2 Classic server in autoscale group to MongoDB inside VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I have a group of servers inside autoscale group (ASG) running in `EC2 Classic`. 
In new project we setup MongoDB inside a `VPC`.

The thing is we want to connect from each instance in `EC2 Classic ASG` to MongoDB in `VPC`. Checked many documents and I found that there is only way to do it is open rules in `VPC` to allow access `27017` from public IP of instances in `EC2 Classic`. But servers on ASG are usually changed and new server can not connect to VPC.

I'm thinking to setup `auth` in `MongoDB` then open port `27017` to all :(

Do you guys have any solutions for this case?

Thanks!

PS: I also tried ClassicLink but this only link individual instance in EC2Classic to VPC. I can write a script to automatically links the instance to VPC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ClassicLink** to achieve this, please check [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-classiclink.html) for details.

Edited:
"If you use Auto Scaling, you can create an Auto Scaling group with instances that are **automatically linked** to a specified ClassicLink-enabled VPC at launch. For more information, see [Linking EC2-Classic Instances to a VPC in the Auto Scaling Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/autoscalingsubnets.html#as-ClassicLink)."

Comment: ClassicLink only link single Instance to VPC. So I have to write a script that automatically links the new instances in ASG to VPC (?)

Comment: It is not necessary to script anything, you need just modify Launch Configuration for your ASG. I edited my answer, please check the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/autoscalingsubnets.html#as-ClassicLink).

Comment: thank you. I did not check the doc carefully. Linking ASG instances to VPC solved my problem. If I have multi VPCs and the Classic instances have to connect to them then it would be nightmare :) I should move all my instances into VPC soon.